# Whitelist inbound IP address for Azure WebApp?

Tags: azure, networking

I would like to restrict access to some *Web Apps* I am developing on Azure through a whitelist of allowed in-bound IP addresses. I have achieved this using *Network Security Group*, applied to a VM. I can also see how I can achieve this using a *App Service Environment*, but this is very costly. Is there any way of applying a *Network Security Group* to a *Web App*? Or can I add a *Network Security Group* to a *Virtual Network*? Or is there another method that I'm overlooking?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can restrict IP addresses in the web.config using the ipSecurity element like so:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
     <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
       <add ipAddress="XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" allowed="true" />
     </ipSecurity>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Full documentation on the ipSecurity element: https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity

Azure Web App support for the feature:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/ip-and-domain-restrictions-for-windows-azure-web-sites/

Comment: Will mark this as answered - thanks. I'll have to work out how to configure web.config through the Azure portal, which I'm sure will be fine. But - this approach entails applying the settings for each webapp in turn. Is there approach which I could apply to multiple apps simultaneously - without the expense of an App Service Environment?

Comment: You do not need an ASE.  You can just edit your web.config and include it in your project that gets deployed to Azure.

Comment: FWIW: according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52471336/is-it-necessary-to-add-azure-ip-datacenter-ips-to-app-service-whitelist using the [Azure App Service Static IP Restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions) (feature from Azure Portal) is "better than having just the web.config `<ipsecurity>` configuration".  (Without having any knowledge on the matter myself, I accidentally ran into this and the referred question/answer, which seem highly related.  I will need to refine my search...)